# PyCharm Import from another project

Tags: python, pycharm

There are two projects (two folders)

```
project1
- directoryM
-- fileA

project2
- directoryN
-- fileB
```

How can I import Class from fileB to fileA?

```
from project2.directoryN.fileB import Class
```

does not work

Comment: from pages_inside.personnel.signatures import DigitalSignatures

http://joxi.ru/DrlzpRPcJjBW2P

Comment: You need to either put `project2` in your `PYTHON_PATH` for python to find it, or put `project2` inside `project1` or start your project from the parent folder of `project1` & `project2`

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this by modifying your `PYTHONPATH` for the interpreter. To do this, you can edit the run configurations of your script, to append a path to your current `PYTHONPATH`. Go to "Edit Configurations" and then go to environment variables, and then append the path that you want to append to the `PYTHONPATH` variable.